# Cloud Firestore's audit logs includes delete collections?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, audit-logging

I understand that audit logs includes by default Admin activities like 'delete' but I can't find any logs in the GCP logs registry related to created or deleted collections in my Firestore project.

I used the following query:

```json
resource.type=("datastore_database" OR "datastore_index")
logName=( 
        "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
        OR "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
        OR "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event"
        OR "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fpolicy"
 )
```

Edited to fix projects path (thanks to Javier M)

Comment: Looks like there is no audit logs for console actions, even for deleting a collection
https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/AiHxmsaTnkg/m/TIy67pbgAQAJ

Comment: Looks like only a very restricted set of Firebase storage operations are audited: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/cloud-audit-logging/firebase-storage?hl=en
But looks like a bigger set of Firestore operations are audited, including DeleteOperation, but I can´t find any of them in the logs: 
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DeleteOperation Audit log

This method, seen under [**ADMIN WRITE** audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging#audited_operations), are related to long running operations, which [are API calls that takes a long time to complete](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#operations). Thus, the method will [erase the long-running operation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.longrunning#google.longrunning.Operations.DeleteOperation) (meaning that the client is no longer interested on its result). **It has nothing to do with deleting entries in a Cloud Firestore instance.**

### Delete Collection

You cannot see logs for Delete Collection simply because [you can't delete a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#:%7E:text=you%20do%20not%20need%20to%20%22create%22%20or%20%22delete%22%20collections). Instead, [you need to delete all the documents and sub documents you have under the Collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections).

Therefore, what you'll see in the logs referring as delete will be for *deleting a document* and *deleting a field*. Once all documents are deleted, you can assume a Collection is deleted as well.

You can see a Collection as a namespace or as a container (which is how the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections) refers to it) for documents.

Answer (score 1):

Data access logs for Firestore are [disabled by default](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging#available-logs). You need to [explicitly enable](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable) them to receive logs.

On the other hand, you're querying logs wrongly as you're missing `projects/` before `PROJECT_ID`, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging#viewing_logs). Therefore, you should use:

```json
logName=(
    "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
    OR "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
    OR "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event"
    OR "projects/PROJECT_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fpolicy")
```

You could also [query logs from methodName](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging#data-access-audit-logs:-data_read-and-data_write). For instance, everytime you create a new Collection or Field in Firestore, [`Write`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Write) method will be used and logged. Thus, you could perform queries as:

```json
protoPayload.methodName="google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Write"
```

#### **Edit:** Information about Delete operation logs as requested by @Troglo

You can see logs for every deletion done on Fields, Documents and Collections under the [Write](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#write) method, as it holds information on every write operation, such as [delete](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#:%7E:text=document%20to%20write.-,delete,-string). However, querying by `methodName="google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Write"` will output all write operations done so far.

Alternatively, you could use the `request` object to build a query as it holds information about Write fields, as `update` or `delete`. Therefore:

**Deletion logs for any collection under your project**

```json
protoPayload.request.writes.delete:"projects/[PROJECT-ID]/databases/(default)/documents/"
```

**Deletion logs for a specific collection**

```json
protoPayload.request.writes.delete:"projects/[PROJECT-ID]/databases/(default)/documents/[COLLECTION-ID]"
```

Notice the use of `:` ("has", matches any substring) instead of `=` (equal) to build queries. The first one has a lower performance compared to the latter.

##### Important:

Please bear in mind that, as per today (26 October, 2021), these [Data Access audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging#:%7E:text=DATA_READ%20and%20DATA_WRITE-,preview,-This%20product%20or) are in *preview*. Please, check the [conditions](https://cloud.google.com/terms/service-terms#1) and [stage description](https://cloud.google.com/products#product-launch-stages) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Javier. But in that document  'DeleteOperation' is listed as an ADMIN_WRITE action, that are enabled by default.
Thanks for the query by methodName, looks useful. ANd for the projects/ path, I´m using it but deleted by error when replacing the PROJECT_ID, I´ll try to fix it in the question

Comment: Hello @Troglo! I've added more information in the same answer (to keep track of any possible useful information for anyone reading this entry). Please, let me know if it clarifies your question.

Comment: Your answer in very complete and useful for Data Access audit logs that are disabled by default. But my doubt is about DELETING a COLLECTION: In Firestore's official docs (cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging?hl=en ) looks like some ADMIN operations are audited, including DeleteOperation, but I can't find any of them in my logs.
Is required to enable DataAccess to log a DELETE COLLECTION operation?

Comment: I've posted another answer trying to clarify your questions. Please take a look and let me know if everything is clear.

Comment: Thanks Javier for both of your answers. The other answer specifically my main issue but this one has a lot of usefiul information for anyone working with Firestore´s logs.